# En un select option aparecer otro dato mas

Tags: php, mysql

Hola buenas tardes amigos quisiera que en un select option se pudiera mostrar al lado la cedula y el nombre dos datos en una opcion por el momento tengo este codigo

```
$html .= "<option value='".$row['cedula']."'>".$row['cedula']."</option>";
```

algo asi pero que aparezca en mi select option quisiera implantarle el nombre 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Lo que tratas de hacer es que se sustituya el valor del select por los datos de la cédula y el nombre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ya obtienes el nombre solo concatenalo así:

```
$html .= "<option value='".$row['cedula']."'>".$row['cedula']." | ".$row['nombre']."</option>";
```

suponiendo que `$row['nombre']` ya lo obtienes.